# Does Hive create new data when you use the insert into command?

Tags: hive

I have questions regarding the "insert into" and "insert overwrite" commands in Hive.

I have a CSV file in HDFS. I want to extract values from few columns into a hive table. I load the full content into a HIVE table with one STRING column. I create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_drivers (col_value STRING) STORED AS TEXTFILE
```

I load the data:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/maria_dev/drivers.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE temp_drivers
```

Each line of my CSV file is a line in the col_value column.

I create a second table:

```
CREATE TABLE drivers (driverId INT, name STRING, ssn BIGINT, location 
STRING, certified STRING, wageplan STRING)
```

Then I insert some data from the first table into the second table by calling regexp_extract, let's say:

```
insert overwrite table drivers
SELECT
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*),?){1}', 1) driverId,
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*),?){2}', 1) name,
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*),?){3}', 1) ssn,
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*),?){4}', 1) location,
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*),?){5}', 1) certified,
regexp_extract(col_value, '^(?:([^,]*),?){6}', 1) wageplan
from temp_drivers
```

The commands are available in this tutorial on Hortonworks:
https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/how-to-process-data-with-apache-hive/

**Two questions:**

- Does this second command write new data in HDFS to backup the second table. If yes, what would be the alternative to prevent HIVE form creating new data?
- Can I do insert into instead of insert overwrite to append new data everytimeI receive a new CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

1) The second command :

LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/maria_dev/drivers.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE temp_drivers

will overwrite temp_drivers table and load the data which is present in drivers.csv

if you have multiple csv files which need to be loaded to temp_drivers table you can use below commands:
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/maria_dev/data1.csv' INTO TABLE temp_drivers;
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/maria_dev/data2.csv' INTO TABLE temp_drivers;

2) Yes you need to do Insert into to append the new data to the existing data

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I think my first question was not clear. I meant:
Does the **insert overwrite** command write new data in HDFS to backup the **drivers** table. If yes, what would be the alternative to prevent HIVE form creating new data?

Comment: @DavidL "insert overwrite" command does not do any backups. It moves all previous contents of "drivers" table into the ".Thrash" directory located in the current user's HDFS directory and loads the result of "select" into "drivers" table

Comment: well if you consider ".Trash" folder as a sort of backup, then, yes, the data is backed up, but the ".Trash" is emptied periodically so the data will eventually disappear from HDFS altogether

Comment: However, it seems that it creates a file in hdfs to back up the table drivers when I insert data (independently of into or overwrite). Could it come from the "select statement" into the "insert overwrite" command? I do not think that it extracts the columns from the file loaded in the temp_drivers. So I understand that the select statement extracts information that are written in a file to back up the table drivers. Am I totally wrong?

Comment: I would add that it seems that the query result file from the select statement backs up the drivers table. So this command has written a new file. So if I have a lot of raw data that I query using the select statement, the query result file would be big and then the size of data in hdfs would increase as well, right? In the long run, it might be problematic no? Is there an alternative?